# Good Dynamics iOS processing

Tags: ios, multithreading, encryption, grand-central-dispatch, good-dynamics

I'm working on an iOS app using Good Dynamics that can be used to download documents from a server. I've found that when downloading multiple files at once (maybe around 40mb worth of data, among 5 different documents) the UI hangs for a bit. I've known it'd be a problem for a while, so we set up a background thread to handling saving the received data to disk off of the main queue.

Our problem is that we're still seeing the UI hang up a bit. As I understand it, GD has to decrypt the data before it is available to the app. I imagine that could take a good amount of processing too and would be better handled off of the main queue. I thought that if we placed the code that sends the request on the background queue, maybe the code that decrypts and notifies our code of the received data would run on the background queue as well. However, even when we send the request on the background queue the delegate methods for the request are called on the main queue.

So my question is this: is there a way to move the heavy processing in GD to the background queue?

Comment: I've no experience with Good Dynamics. But it would be helpful to explain whether they provide an SDK, or if you implement the network code yourself. In any case, show the code! ;)   -- Ah well, the answer is yes - no matter what.

Comment: They provide an SDK and I can't provide any source code unfortunately. This is something that would need to be answered by someone who has experience with good dynamics before.

Comment: Then it is likely impossibly to improve anything - since it is likely also closed source. In that case, your only option is to contact their support.

Comment: Ya we have reached out but no one has gotten back to us. I was hoping someone on stack would be familiar enough to provide some insight.